# How to use socket.io in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, socket.io, aurelia

I am trying to use socket.io with the aurelia framework.
When loading the page, the data is pulled from the socket server, but afterwards, it doesn't listen.

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
var socket = io.connect( 'http://localhost:3000' );

export class Settings {
    newstate = '';

    constructor() {
        socket.on( 'users',   // <- only works once (when loading the page) but doesn't listen after
            function ( userlist ) {
                this.users = userlist;
            }.bind( this ) );
    }

    addstate() {
        socket.emit( 'add state', this.newstate ); // <- works flawless
        this.newstate = '';
    }
}
```

I love aurelia, but I keep failing with integrating socket.io.

Answer (score 5):

Try binding your listener in activate() instead of constructor().

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
var socket = io.connect( 'http://localhost:3000' );

export class Settings {
    newstate = '';

    activate() {
        socket.on( 'users',   // <- only works once (when loading the page) but doesn't listen after
            function ( userlist ) {
                this.users = userlist;
            }.bind( this ) );
    }

    addstate() {
        socket.emit( 'add state', this.newstate ); // <- works flawless
        this.newstate = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The constructor() only gets called once when Settings is created (think singleton), then activate() is called each time the view is visited, including the first time.

Comment: Correct. All data that the viewmodel is dependent on from the server-side should be handled in activate or even canActivate. This allows you to return a Promise and delay loading of the viewmodel until it resolves.